# Как запустить JS функцию из другого файла по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть кнопка и файл main.js.
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, например в консоль выводилось сообщение?

```html
<body>
  <p><button>Button</button></p>
</body>
```

Comment: код приложи пожалуйста

Comment: @СергейПетрашко готово, но у меня нету js кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну приблизительно все должно выглядеть так ( функцию опиши в файле с скриптом):

```js
 function clickListener(){
   console.log('test');
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <p><button onclick ="clickListener()" >Button</button></p>
</body>
<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
```